# method/metric of comparing two random samples and their impact

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sampling

I have the following problem. Given a set S of N=100000 data elements (time series data from solar observations) I need to extract a random sample R of size n=20 and then for each element in S compute the minimum distance to the points in R. That minimum distance is declared to be the rank of the element.

The problem is that the N data is not available all from the beginning but it is processed in parallel, in a distributed fashion, being available only partitions of M=8000 elements.

I was thinking to generate a random sample for each partition and compute the ranks per partition, but then the ranks won't have the same meaning when compared across partitions since the partitions have different random samples (a point with rank=0.2 in a partition is not the same with a point with rank=0.2 in other partition).
Do you have any idea of how can be unified the ranks globally, after they are computed locally, per partition?
Is any way of comparing how similar 2 random samples are?
Based on that, can we derive a metric to measure the impact of one random sample on a rank?
The final goal is to unify all ranks and to have a correct global rank instead of partition based rank.
Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It is impossible to do this in one pass if by "random sample" you mean every element of $S$ has an equal chance of being selected. In particular, the very last element has a positive chance of being in $R$. But to compute the "ranks" you would need to compute the distances from every element of $S$ to its last element, whence the need for a second pass (or something equivalent amounting to storing all the information needed for computing the minimum distance from all of $S$ to any arbitrary point; such information would suffice to reproduce $S$ up to order).

Answer (score 0):

You first select (with replacement) $20$ partitions, and tell the worker in charge of each partition to 
select a random element and report it back to top level.  That gives you your
sample $R$. Send that to each worker and have them calculate in parallel the rank of each element in their partition.

Comment: Not sure I understood your answer.
The data is not available all from the beginning but it is split in files each one having 8000 elements, let's say F1, F2, ... Fn
Let's also consider a map/reduce approach.
Each mapper deals with a Fi with 8000 elements. How can I have a global random sample of size 20 in each mapper?

Comment: You select (with replacement) $20$ integers $a_i$ in $[1,2,\ldots n]$.  For $i$ from 1 to 20, mapper number $a_i$ is told to select one element from its file, and report it back to the top level.  The $20$ elements returned constiture your random sample.  I assume that's not too many to store at top level and communicate to all the mappers.

Comment: Let's say I have 125 mappers. From your comment I understood that only 20 mappers from 125 contribute to the random sample. The question is if this is still a "random sample" since not all elements have equal chance to be selected (the elements from the rest of 105 mappers are not considered)?

Comment: It is random, because those $20$ are chosen randomly (if the mappers have files of different sizes, their probabilities of being chosen should be in proportion to the file sizes).